# set from the union of elements contained in two lists

Tags: programming-languages

this is for a pre-interview questioner.  i believe i have the answer just wanted to get confirmation that im right.

Part 1 - Tell me what this code does, and its big-O performance
Part 2 - Re-write it yourself and tell me the big-O performance of your solution

```
 def foo(a, b):
     """ a and b are both lists """
     c = []
     for i in a:
         if is_bar(b, i):
             c.append(i)
     return unique(c)

  def is_bar(a, b):
     for i in a:
         if i == b:
             return True
     return False

  def unique(arr):
     b = {}
     for i in arr:
         b[i] = 1

     return b.keys()
```

ANSWERS:
It creates a set from the union of elements contained in two lists.  It big O performance is O(n2)

my solution which i believe achieves O(n)

```
Set A = getSetA();
Set B = getSetB();

Set UnionAB = new Set(A);
UnionAB.addAll(B);

for (Object inA : a)
   if(B.contains(inA))
      UnionAB.remove(inA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the original code is doing an intersection not a union. It's traversing all the elements in the first list (a) and checking if it exists in the second list (b), in which case it is adding it to list c. Then it is returning the unique elements from c. Performance of O(n^2) seems right.

Comment: ok thank you.  so my coded answer which is a union would be wrong, right?